# integration between active directory and EPM

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, active-directory, biztalk

I recently come to know that there are ADWS(Active directory Web Service)
i Want to read/write data from active directory using biz talk server through WCF adapter.
Are there any documentation or blogs about it or how to receive or send data to active directory

regards,

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the /n software BizTalk Adapters includes an LDAP Adapter that can be used to access active directory http://www.nsoftware.com/products/biztalk/adapters/ldap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To use ADWS you need to know the AD server name and then u can import it in BizTalk.

You can also refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908(v=ws.10).aspx
and
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4f275285-2fad-4587-a9b9-afa1704ad504/active-directory-web-services.